# Es6 Restify parameter typeof throws error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am newbie to ES6. Just wanted to know the typeof for the spread parameter.
http://es6-features.org/#RestParameter
I  am not sure why i am not able to print the typeof for spread parameter could someone explain the reason.

Please find the snippet below:

```
function restify(...x){ 
    console.log(typeof (...x));
}
restify([1,2,3,5,]);
```

Comment: Why are you spreading it again inside of `typeof`?

Comment: And why are you passing a sparse array (`[1,2,3,5,]`). The last entry is empty.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? `x` will always be an array.

Comment: @Rakesh What is expected result?

Comment: `typeof` is not a function. `...x` is only valid in specific contexts (parameter list, function call, array literal, destructing). `typeof` is not one of them and it wouldn't make sense either.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the spread operator only in the parameters definition

```
const restify = (...x) => {
  console.log(typeof x);
}

restify([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Which will print `Object`. I used `const` and `arrow functions` which are also ES6 features, check out http://es6-features.org/

Comment: _"You should use the spread operator only in the parameters definition"_ Not sure what you mean by "only in the parameters definition"? Note `...` is not an operator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper

Comment: `...` is an operator, check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: 1) The article you are referring to says spread **syntax**, not operator. 2) it has nothing to do with the question. The OP uses rest parameters

Comment: @zeroflagL OP does use spread element within body of function.

Comment: @zeroflagL did you see the link? "Operators/Spread_operator". Another reference (from microsoft): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn919259(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof x`.

```
function restify(...x){ 
    console.log(typeof x);
}
restify([1,2,3,5,]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the answer with the explanation

Comment: @Rakesh No worries. _"I got the answer with the explanation"_ Not sure what you mean? What was expected result of calling `typeof (...x)`?

Comment: Apparently i was using in the wrong way. If i need to print the typeof spread variable there is no reason to add the spread operator i was using it in the wrong way that was the explanation i understood from the above answers.

Comment: @Rakesh Was not sure if you were trying to call `typeof` on elements of the array